# Counting amount of people in HOG/HAAR detection

Tags: ros, kinect, turtlebot, package, people

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!!

I'm using the [hog_haar_person_detect](https://github.com/angusleigh/hog_haar_person_detection_ros) package with turtlebot and kinect for people detection, and i need to identify the number of peoples (number of detections) that the algorithm is detecting.

The main objective is to detect the medium amount of people in front of the robot and save this information in a variable (int). I'm using a classifier instead of the [openni_tracker](http://wiki.ros.org/openni_tracker) package for 2 reasons: The classifier gets the rgb image from the kinect topic and it isn't related to the max range of the sensor, the other reason is the speed, this package is faster than openni_tracker's.

I can get the people detection information from the part of the code which draws the detection rectangles on the screen, **but i can't count it.**

**My question is: Is it possible to identify the number of people through this code? How can i do that? Is there a better/another choice to consider?**

*Thanks so much in advance!*

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205997/counting-amount-of-people-in-hog/haar-detection/) by [Phelipe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21088/phelipe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 74 on 2015-03-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Phelipe!

To count the number of detections from the HOG detector use:

```
int num_detected_persons = detected_person.size();
```

To count the number of detections from the HAAR detector use:

```
int num_detected_faces = detected_faces.size();
```

An alternative for the kinect which I would recommended trying out is the [ground-based RGBD detection](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/ground_based_rgbd_people_detection.php#ground-based-rgbd-people-detection) in the PCL by Matteo Munaro

---

Originally posted by [Angus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2171/angus/) with karma: 438 on 2015-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Phelipe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21088/phelipe/) on 2015-03-27**:
Thanks, i figured that out some time after posting the question, but thank you anyway!! I'll check that ground-based out too.